# Error passing custom options to radarChartJS

Tags: r, chart.js, radar-chart

I'm trying to pass custom options to `chartJSRadar` per http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-creating-a-chart-with-options. In this example, I try passing a simple title but am faced with this error:

`Error in validateCssUnit(sizeInfo$width) : 
  CSS units must be a single-element numeric or character vector`

Example code:

```R
library(radarchart)

labs <- c("Communicator", "Data Wangler", "Programmer",
          "Technologist",  "Modeller", "Visualizer")

scores <- list(
  "Rich" = c(9, 7, 4, 5, 3, 7),
  "Andy" = c(7, 6, 6, 2, 6, 9),
  "Aimee" = c(6, 5, 8, 4, 7, 6)
)


opList <- list(title=list(display='true', text='Title'))
chartJSRadar(scores = scores, labs = labs, maxScale = 10, opList)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to change your `opList` argument slightly.  `chartJSRadar` uses `...` as a place to pass additional options.  In your code, the `opList` is assumed to be the `width` argument.  Generally, I would say most `htmlwidgets` put the `height` and `width` last so this does not happen, but `chartJSRadar` does not follow this convention.

This should work, but it doesn't, so exploring source of the bug.  It appears the older version of `chartJS` on which this is based does not provide `title`.  I added code to show how to manually add a `title`.

```
library(radarchart)

labs <- c("Communicator", "Data Wangler", "Programmer",
          "Technologist",  "Modeller", "Visualizer")

scores <- list(
  "Rich" = c(9, 7, 4, 5, 3, 7),
  "Andy" = c(7, 6, 6, 2, 6, 9),
  "Aimee" = c(6, 5, 8, 4, 7, 6)
)


chartJSRadar(
  scores = scores, labs = labs, maxScale = 10,
  title = list(display = TRUE, text = "Custom Title")
)
```

I quickly hacked together an update you can try with, but it has not been tested and is not ready for pull yet.

```
devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/radarchart@update/2.1.6")
```

Comment: Ah makes sense. Ok I'm investigating source code now that I know it's a bug as well.

Comment: I think this is an old version of `chartjs` which did not have `title`.

Comment: Ok so I tried adding a legend and that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: options are very limited in that release.  I will try to submit pull in a little with the newest.

Comment: added in answer to `install_github`